# how to call AWS Cognito ListUser API

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cognito

I am trying to call ListUser Api of AWS Cognito in postman by using domain name https://domain-name.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com of userpool but I don't know how to call API of AWS cognito. Could any one know this?
referred this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009255/listing-cognito-userpool-users-on-aws-lambda

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to work on aws cognito sdk or aws has facility to call directly API in application?